# How to execute a function after click particular button in PyQt5 Dialog Button Box?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

Here is my Dialog Button Box design on Python:

```
    self.buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox(Frame)
    self.buttonBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 216, 144, 27))
    self.buttonBox.setFont(font)
    self.buttonBox.setAcceptDrops(False)
    self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Discard|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Save)
    self.buttonBox.setObjectName("buttonBox")
```

There are two buttons as shown above, which are `Discard` and `Save`. How to execute a particular unique function when I click `Save` or `Discard`. What I have tried is:

```
    self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.save)
    self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.discard)
```

However, the function execute only when I clicked `Save` and did not work when I clicked `Discard`. How to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

`Discard` is a `destructive` button, not a `reject` button.  You could either:

- Use `Cancel`, `Close`, or `Abort` and link to the `rejected` signal as you are already doing
- If you need to use `Discard`, connect to the `clicked` signal and just verify in your `self.discard` function that the clicked button (passed with the signal) was the `Discard` button before doing anything

Comment: There's no `buttonClicked` signal, only [clicked](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialogbuttonbox.html#clicked).

Comment: Apologies, I was thinking of QMessageBox - you are right that QDialogButtonBox uses 'clicked' instead.  I will edit my post to reflect, but I think the same solution applies.